# Angular components in html table cells overlap

Tags: css, angular

I am using Angular CLI: 8.3.14 and Node: 12.18.0.

I have components A, B, and C, and I tried to put them into individual cells in a traditional HTML table, but they come out overlap, I've tried many CSS formatting tricks, below are a few of them that I tried, but none worked.

```
.gfg { 
   border-collapse:separate; 
   border-spacing:0 15px;
} 

table td.expand {
    width: 99%;
    height: 99%;
}

<table class="gfg" width="100%">
    <tr> <td class="expand"> <componentA></componentA> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td class="expand"> <componentB></componentB> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td class="expand"> <componentC></componentC> </td> </tr>
</table>
```

One more piece of information: this whole thing is also inside another `<div>` that I have made its `height:100vh`, so I don't think it is a space issue, what I want is to have the components stack up on top of one another.

Comment: On the component(s) scss add `:host { display: block; overflow: hidden }` and the individual classes on each cell seem redundant. Could just make the table height/width 100% and the cells will have the same effect but maybe it's just the example. Which is still tough to reproduce.

Comment: the `hidden` bit only makes the third row cover up the second row content.

Comment: I'd have to see a reproducible example then because it sounds like there's more going on here. A component in the DOM is basically just an inline element created with the custom element api. Whatever's in it as a child or how it's contained in a parent is your culprit and the simple example doesn't seem to reproduce the description.

Comment: The componentA, B, and C each contains a table and a couple of buttons and that's it. This is the gist of the problem, that is, a simple HTML table cannot seem to handle angular component as its cell content without overlapping each other.